# Problems with getting jQuery to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'am new to jQuery and cant seem to get it to work on my computer locally. I have saved the code from production jQuery 2.1.1 as jquery.min.js . But when I try to use jquery in projects it does not work. If I click on the jquery.min.js file that I saved, it gives up a Microsoft Script Error  of "'default view' is null or not an object". I have been using this code to see if jQuery was installed. Any Ideas?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Learning jQuery</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      if (typeof jQuery != "undefined") {
         alert('jQuery is installed!');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? When you load your page, do you get the alert or not?

Comment: And, is jquery.min.js in the same directory as the HTML page?

Comment: I dont get alert when I load page, just jQuery does not work.

Comment: Yes in same directory as HTML page.

Comment: Put a `}` after your alert statement

Comment: Checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: -1 not enough jQuery

Comment: can you just `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>` add this ..... and close your if condition and check if it works?

Comment: whats the error ur getting

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing curly brace for your IF statement.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Learning jQuery</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      if (typeof jQuery != "undefined") {
         alert('jQuery is installed!');
      }                                  //  <---- Right here!
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you believe that to be the problem, vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo.

Comment: It is clearly the problem... I've tested.  However, it could be a syntax error rather than a typo, hence a coding error, hence fair game.  Perhaps someone with more reputation than I should make the decision about closing.

Comment: He could as well remove the opening brace!

Comment: True, but that leaves a nasty trap when someone "adds a line" to the IF.  Always use braces... always!

Comment: and I am sure for closing braces he should get error in console but he is saying that no error !!! thats what is puzzling me!!

Comment: Yes.  I'm sure too.  When I run OP's code with Firebug, it says `SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement` and gives me the line number.

Answer (score 0):

try using jQuery from CDN to check the problem [source : http://jquery.com/download/]

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

other way to include it is like this : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also there is closing braces missing in the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Learning jQuery</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      if (typeof jQuery != "undefined") {
         alert('jQuery is installed!');
       }//** <--------here is the missing closing braces **

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `src` address without protocol is treated as local resource, you must specify the protocol e.g. `http://`

Comment: The snip in hitesh's answer appears to be copied straight from Google, and is *does* work; I've just tested it.

Comment: You don´t need to specify a protocol. The browser will do that for you.

Comment: Oh, duh!  Of course you did, and I would know that if I had read carefully.  Sorry.

Comment: I am not sure if person who has asked question, is checking the answer ... there is no reply from him ?...

Comment: @putvande This only works with `src="//code.jquery.com` and _does not_ work with `src="code.jquery.com`

Comment: Thought your were talking about the first one. I´m guessing OP has the "jquery.min.js" as a local file.

Comment: @putvande : yes he has local file .. but I wanted to crosscheck where the problem was so I asked him to include it from CDN

Comment: Added in closing brace and didnt work again. Also tried using jQuery from CDN but still not working.

Comment: what is the error you are getting can u copy the error and paste it in question [edit the question]

Comment: If adding the closing brace did not fix it, and you're not getting console errors. then your copy of jquery.min.js is not where you think it is.  Do what hitesh says and load it from CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some chnages to your code ,please check it

1.closed the curly bracket.

2.changed the min file.

I think the major error is in syntax,because you have not closed the curly bracket of if conditions.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Learning jQuery</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
  </head>

  <body>
     <script>
      if (typeof jQuery != "undefined") {
         alert('jQuery is installed!');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```